# Joining an ID with a NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to join a table of data to another table, but one of the ID that I'll be joining on is NULL. However, I have a specific ID I want it to link to with the NULLs.

I might be oversimplifying this question too much with this example, but I'm hoping this will point me in the right direction. So suppose we have the two tables below.

TABLE1:

```
    Name    ID
    A       1
    B       2
    C       NULL
```

TABLE2:

```
    ID      Value
    1       4
    2       5
    3       6
```

What would I need to do in the query to get an output like this?

OUTPUT:

```
    Name    Value
    A       4
    B       5
    C       6
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: On the join condition use ISNULL condition like ON ISNULL(t1.ID,specific id) = t2.ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly check it in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT name, value
FROM   table1
JOIN   table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id) OR 
                 (table1.id IS NULL AND table2.id = 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Join using COALESCE(ID,3) instead of table1.id

Answer (score 2):

If you know the specific ID:**Use ISNULL**

```
SELECT name, value
FROM   table1
JOIN   table2 ON ISNULL(table1.id,3) = table2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.Name AS Name , coalesce(t2.ID,standardvaluefornulls) AS ID
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Value = t2.Value
```

EDIT: this wouldn't work with a normal join because it would skip the rows that didn't have a value for t2.value so keeping in mind that your left table (t1) is the one that will always have a value for 'Value' you can use a left join so even the ones without a result in table2 will get the standard null value as result

SQLFIDDLE to prove it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2e15/12

Answer (score 0):

you can join on multiple conditions and join your specific scenario in a secondary join condition as such:

```
select name, value
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    or (t1.id is null and t2.id = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, value
FROM   table1
JOIN   table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id or table1.id IS NULL)
```

Comment: This might answer the question, but it were even better if you could add some explanation. Thanks.